# Passing variable to index function through the url

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I have set up a controller called links, i have the routes to several pages being directed to this controller and within this controller I have a number of different functions for accessing different parts of the page through ajax calls. Here is a sample from my routes config:

```
    $route['games'] = "links";   
    $route['games/ajax_pager'] = "links/ajax_pager";
    $route['games/ajax_dbr/(:any)'] = "links/ajax_dbr/$1";
    $route['games/linkinfo/(:num)'] = "links/linkinfo/$1";
    $route['games/linkobj/(:num)'] = "links/linkobj/$1";
    $route['links'] = "links";
    $route['links/ajax_pager'] = "links/ajax_pager";
    $route['links/ajax_dbr/(:any)'] = "links/ajax_dbr/$1";
    $route['links/linkinfo/(:num)'] = "links/linkinfo/$1";
```

what I would like to do now is have a variable from the second segment of the url passed to the index function if it doesnt match up with any of the functions routed to above. So something like this:

```
$route['games/(:any)'] = "links/$1";
```

but this isn't working is there any way to do this without creating a new function. Hope this is clear - please let me know if any clarification is required. An dthanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what error/"isn't working" symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: Well I was getting a lot of undefined variable errors but I have just realised that is because it is following the 404 override route (which I havent set up yet) - wondering if I can use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first segment is the controller, the second segment is the function and the third can be your variable. So if you whish to  send a variable to the index function of the links controller this would look like this:

```
$route['games/(:any)'] = "links/index/$1";
```

No when someone browses to index.php/games/atestvariable the index function of the links controller with variable atestvariable will be called.